# Create 2 external lines with the same regexps and priorities in Asterisk

Tags: regex, asterisk

I'm running Asterisk 11.4.0 and I need to make a feature: when I'm calling a number matching the specific mask, one of 2 (or 3) external lines can be used, so the line for each such call must be chose randomly.

For example, I've got lines A and B, and I've the number mask _XXXX. That means, when I call a number, matching this mask, it must use randomly A or B line.

I can create a rule in dialplan:

```
exten => _XXXX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@A,30,r)
```

Asterisk denies creation of line:

```
exten => _XXXX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@B,30,r)
```

How can I code this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the same extension and same priority.

Usually external lines(FXO, E1) are put in one group and you can call this group in your dialplan.

But you can do the follow dialplan using the RAND function:

```
exten => _XXXX,1,Goto(${RAND(2,3)})
exten => _XXXX,2,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@A,30,r)
exten => _XXXX,3,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@B,30,r)
```

The RAND function will be chose randomly the priority 2 or 3